# how can i check if NSUrl is a valid image url?

Tags: iphone, ios, sdwebimage

I'm using `SDWebImage` library and I have this code:

```
     [cell.imgLogo setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[item objectForKey:@"s_logo"]]         placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default.png"]];
```

I have tweak the library `SDWebImage` a little bit to ignore empty string or a NSUrl with empty string in method `downloadWithURL: delegate: options: userInfo:`:

```
     if ([url isKindOfClass:NSString.class])
     {
         if ([(NSString *)url length] > 0) {
              url = [NSURL URLWithString:(NSString *)url]; 
         } else {
              return;
         }
    }
    else if (![url isKindOfClass:NSURL.class])
    {
         url = nil; // Prevent some common crashes due to common wrong values passed like NSNull.null for instance
    }
    else if ([url isKindOfClass:NSURL.class]) {
         if ([[url absoluteString] length] > 0) {
              //valid url
         } else {
             return;
         }
     }
```

So now it works with empty string and just to display its default image but the problem is when it comes to a string that is not an image url like:

```
     http://beta.xxxxxxx.com/gangnamwe?to=boko
```

It displays nothing, it removes the placeholder image and displays nothing.

So how will I identify a valid image url? or is there any better work around for this?

Your help are much appreaciated.

Comment: @Rajneesh071: i have tried your solution once and it worked, al though we went to a different solution to solve the problem, we need modification to our server end.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can check after getting `NSData` from `NSURL` . You can use [GCD](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) to download data

here is an example i created which save your image in photo library.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("com.getImage", NULL), ^(void) {

        NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRKII9COB-hvMef4Zvb9XYVbXKDFZHJAHwwzzGyMiy_b-q65GD43Chd37jH"]];
        UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
        if (image==nil) {
            //yourImageURL is not valid
            image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];
        }
        else{

            //yourImageURL is valid
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
                //show your image
            });

        }

    });
```

Comment: if the url returns some json or garbage data than this logic will fail.

Comment: Note that `dataWithContentsOfURL` should not be used on the main thread, as it can take a long time to fail. Instead, use `NSURLConnection`'s asynchronous methods.

Comment: @SharonNathaniel: you mean it will crash with json or a web page return?

Comment: @SharonNathaniel ->  now check buddy

Comment: so in this code, if the url is an xml page or a json or any url that is not an image url it goes to image==nil?

Comment: See my answer for a way to check the file type without needing to download the file first.

Answer (score 4):

There is method in NSURL to check if the file exsists.

```
- (BOOL)checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:(NSError **)error
```

Example

```
    NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
    NSError *err;
    if ([theURL checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:&err] == NO)
    {
        NSLog(@"resource not reachable");
    }
```

Comment: if the url returns some json or garbage data than this logic will fail.

Comment: it did not work for me given a valid image URL from server.

Comment: it Returns whether the resource pointed to by a file URL can be reached. Note: "file URL", not Internet or other scheme URL.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a category on NSURL for you :

```
// nsurl+documentTypes.h
@interface NSURL (documentTypes)
- (BOOL)isImageType;
@end

// nsurl+documentTypes.m
@implementation NSURL (documentTypes)

- (BOOL)isImageType
{
    NSString * UTI = (__bridge NSString *)UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension,(__bridge CFStringRef)[self pathExtension],NULL);
    return UTTypeConformsTo((__bridge CFStringRef)UTI, kUTTypeImage);   
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the url ends with some image name or not.You can get the parts of the url in following way:

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://digg.com/news/business/24hr"];
NSString* reducedUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:
    @"%@://%@/%@",
    url.scheme,
    url.host,
    [url.pathComponents objectAtIndex:1]];
```

Now, take the last object of the `pathComponents` and check if it contains .png or .jpg etc.

Comment: worst method. Check olynoise's Answer

Answer (score 0):

In Swift:

```
import Foundation

public extension NSURL {

    public var isImage: Bool {
        return UTI.map{ UTTypeConformsTo($0, kUTTypeImage) } ?? false
    }

    public var UTI: String? {
        var value: AnyObject?
        let _ = try? getResourceValue(&value, forKey: NSURLTypeIdentifierKey)
        return value as? String
    }
}
```

e.g:

```
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/i/Desktop/image.png")
url.isImage //--> true
```